# Params empty on POST request

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to make a POST request sending 2 params using HTTPClient for NodeJS.

```
var HTTPClient = require('httpclient')

var options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    path: '/',
    port: 8081,
    secure: false,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'x-powered-by': 'HTTPClient.js'
    },
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    params:{
        command:'TEST',
        param1:'TEST'
    }
} 

var example1 = new HTTPClient(options)
example1.post('/executeGraph1', function (err, res, body) {
    console.log(typeof body,body);
})
```

Then I am using Express to catch the POST request

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// configure the app to use bodyParser()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '')));

app.post('/executeGraph1', function (req, res) {
   console.log("Got a POST request for grahBar");

   console.log("params",req.params);
   console.log("body",req.body);
   console.log("query",req.query);
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

I have tried solutions in other question like using `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` Or `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));` but evrery time I keep getting empty variables. I have tried looking in properties body,params or query but all three options are empty arrays

Does anybody knows what is going wrong here?

Comment: Change your `Content-Type` -> `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` to -> `'Content-Type': 'application/json`

Comment: @swapnesh I have already tried that but the result is the same :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server code is alright, `req.query` will contain query parameters, but `req.params` is used when your route string is defined like that `/executeGraph1/:paramName` there might be more params prefixed with `:` for e.g `/res1/:param1/res2/:param2/:param3`.

Altough I have not been using httpclient module, adding query string in request url works, e.g

```
example1.post('/executeGraph1?queryParamName=value', function (err, res, body) {
    console.log(typeof body,body);
  })
```

Replacing `params` with `query` in your options variable also work.

I would suggest using https://github.com/request/request instead.

One last thing in your POST handler add as last line `res.end()` if you do not do this your request will hang and wait for timeout. `end` may take argument which will be sent to client.